# Getting next node in mwparserfromhell

Tags: python, mediawiki-api

I am parsing a WikiMedia text using `mwparserfromhell`.

I need to get the places from a page.

As an eg, When I query Muriel using [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=muriel&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json)
 ([Wiki Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muriel)), I am able to get all the headings after parsing by `filter_headings()`. Now I need to get the content under a heading.

I can get the heading ("Places"), but how do I get its content?

Here is the the code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import mwparserfromhell
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json


def main():
    search('muriel')


def search(name):
    wiki_parsed = get_json(name, True)
    headings = wiki_parsed.filter_headings()
    filtered_headings = [heading
                         for heading in headings
                         if heading.title == 'Places']

    if len(filtered_headings) > 0:
        print(filtered_headings[0])

        # ===================================
        # need to get the content inside heading
        #
        # ?????????????????????????????????????


def get_json(name, ignore_cache=False):
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'

    args = {'action': 'query',
            'titles': name,
            'prop': 'revisions',
            'rvprop': 'content',
            'format': 'json'}

    content = get_url_content(url, args)

    data = json.loads(content)
    wiki_text = (list(data['query']['pages'].values())[
                 0]['revisions'][0]['*'])
    parsed = mwparserfromhell.parse(wiki_text)

    return parsed


def get_url_content(url, req_params):
    url = url + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(req_params)
    fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    str_content = fp.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    fp.close()
    return str_content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In MediaWiki syntax, content is not really "inside" the section, the section title is more like an anchor, a marker on the page. That means you can do things like

```
== section 1 ==
{|
|
== section 2 ==
|}
```

which will result in

```
<h2>section 1</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h2>section 2</h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What would be the content of section 1 in this case?

Comment: well I checked and yes, there no childrens inside the `Heading` node. How to get the next node? or sibling node? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, `wiki_parsed.nodes[wiki_parsed.nodes.index(filtered_headings[0]) + 1)` for example. But as I explained it won't necessarily mean what you expect it to mean.

Comment: Although `mwparserfromhell` seems to be unable to deal with nested sections anyway.

Comment: I currently using that first approach which you have mentioned above. Fingers crossed until I face an issue or my scrapper fails. :) Thanks

Comment: Tgr, which python library would you recommend to parse the wiki text?

Comment: There is nothing else. Wikitext is not exactly easily parsable, `mwparserfromhell` is pretty much the only standalone parser in existence (Python or not). You can ask the server to parse it for you, or cut it to sections. You still have to deal with the ambiguity of what a section is, though (see [T114072](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T114072) for more details), although nested sections are relatively rare on Wikipedia.